USPTO Amendment Requirement
Could someone confirm my understanding of USPTO policy is correctly
POLICY: The text of any deleted matter must be shown by strike-through except that double brackets placed before and after the deleted characters may be used to show deletion of five or fewer consecutive characters.
Delete of a sentence over 5 characters should be like this one---strike-through
Delete of 5 or fewer characters should be like [this]
Thank you so much.

Welcome to Ask Patents! The style of SE posts is to avoid adding things like “thanks”.

Yes, that is what is described in 37 CFR § 1.121- Manner of making amendments in applications.

Hi George, Could I know the signature policy, I know I have to sign on the cover letter, but do I need sign on the amended description? if yes, should I sign all the pages or just the last page with my contact detail? I can't find detail explanation on USPTO.

Should be a new question. SE sites are not discussion sites but should be Q and A. It helps others benefit from the question and answers in the future.

noted, I am sorry

It’s not a big deal - please post as a new question.
